# Can I spend from multiple wallets in a single transaction?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Using the command line I know how to `transfer <mix> <address> <amount>`, but is there a way to do this from multiple wallets in one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`monero-wallet-cli` is designed to control one wallet at a time. For security reasons this is a strength.

Ask yourself why you need to do this. It is likely [integrated addresses](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integrated-address), [payment ids](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-id) or [disposable addresses](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disposable-address) can serve the same (account management) purpose and only require one wallet.

Comment: thx, i was just curious .. I've been using `transfer` and `sweep_all` and have been testing with multiple wallets.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is not possible with any current wallet implementation that I know of, it is certainly technically possible to write your own code to construct a transaction that spends outputs that span multiple wallets.

This is because each output has a unique private key, and if you know the output private keys for a set of inputs it does not matter at all what wallet addresses those outputs were sent to.